# Android custom bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

How can i create and adjust the following bottom navigation bar?

[image: bottom navigation bar]

Comment: you 're asking for someone to do your work. that's not how this site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bottom Sheet. Go to some tutorials. You will find exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was looking for